# NetMQ reuse same socket

Tags: c#, amqp, netmq

Is it somehow possible to start for example 2 publishers on the same port or for example a publisher and subscriber simultaneously (both with the >tcp:// prefix)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont be able to run 2 services on the same port at the same time. They would have to be on different ports if they run together. The port number just tells the computer which service on the computer the packets are meant for.

Comment: Is there another way to have bidirectional communication over the same port with NetMQ? Something like bidirectional publish-subscribe over the same port?

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you are asking, why do you want to use the same port? If you are running a publish and subscriber service they will need a separate port each, and will be able to communicate with each other  even if they are on your localhost. Generally speaking, what exactly are you trying to do??

Comment: Basically I want a simple server which receives new orders from clients, and transmits executionreports back. My idea was to have one subscriber on the server for new orders and one publisher on the server for execution reports.